# How do I feature engineer more than 2 new variables in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-engineering

I'm making a model that predicts whether an invidual will buy a product after watching an ad.

Here's the data, (sorry for the size I don't know how to make it smaller):

[image: Data]

I want to add a new column called `AgeRange`, where the value is 0 if age < 27, 1 if 27 <= age < 53, and 2 if age >= 53.

So far I've done this:

```
eng_data = clean_data.copy()
eng_data['AgeRange'] = [0 if i < 27 else 1 for i in eng_data['Age']]
```

but I'm not sure how to add the value 2 if age >= 53.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use nested if

```
eng_data['AgeRange'] = [0 if i < 27 else (1 if (i>=27 and i<53) for i in eng_data['Age']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and `lambda` function to achieve this in a simple means:

```
eng_data['AgeRange'] = eng_data['Age'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < 27  else (1 if x < 53 else 2))
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work! Sorry for the duplicate.